# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substr' of undefined (Chrome/IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, debugging, google-chrome

So just debugging someone else's code, I'd fixed everything in Firefox and now onto Chrome but when I am trying to select an option which selects all child nodes and opens their relevant graphs, I am getting a weird error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substr' of undefined

I know the problem is (apparantly) this line:

```
var graph={id:seqId,entityName:flags[6].substr(1).substr(0,flags[6].length-2),entity:flags[5].substr(1).substr(0,flags[5].length-2),idCounter:flags[4],counterName:flags[3].substr(1).substr(0,flags[3].length-2),ivmanager:flags[7].substr(1).substr(0,flags[7].length-2),chart:null,pointsToShowX:null,borneInf:null,unite:"",idInstance:flagsInstance[2].substr(1).substr(0,flagsInstance[2].length-2),instanceName:flagsInstance[3].substr(1).substr(0,flagsInstance[3].length-2),listPdsNull:new Array(), countInstance:idTreeview+"_"+i, countGraph:-1};
```

But I have no idea why this is causing an error as everything looks correct to me?! substr is used countless times before and after the function so I have no idea why Chrome is throwing this error at me.

The **full function** is as below. I believe the problem is in the second part.

```
function loadGraphs(idTreeview,idSelectGraph)
{

    var count=0;
    var fn=$('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].attributes[1].value;
    fn=fn.substr(12).substr(0,fn.length-2);
    var flags=fn.split(new RegExp(","));
    var data=''; 

    var idInstanceTreeview = idTreeview;

if($('#counterTreeviewUL'+idInstanceTreeview).length == 0)      
{

    var fnInstance=$('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].attributes[1].value;

    var flagsInstance=fnInstance.split(new RegExp(","));

    var graph = {
            id: seqId,
            entityName: flags[6].substr(1).substr(0, flags[6].length - 2),
            entity: flags[5].substr(1).substr(0, flags[5].length - 2),
            idCounter: flags[4],
            counterName: flags[3].substr(1).substr(0, flags[3].length - 2),
            ivmanager: flags[7].substr(1).substr(0, flags[7].length - 2),
            chart: null,
            pointsToShowX: null,
            borneInf: null,
            unite: "",
            idInstance: flagsInstance[2].substr(1).substr(0, flagsInstance[2].length - 2),
            instanceName: flagsInstance[3].substr(1).substr(0, flagsInstance[3].length - 2),
            listPdsNull: new Array(),
            countInstance: idTreeview + "_" + i,
            countGraph: -1
        };

    seqId++;
    graphs[graphsLastId]=graph;
    graphsLastId++;

    }

else 
  {
    for(var i=0;i<$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idInstanceTreeview)[0].children.length;i++)
        ($('#counterTreeviewUL'+idInstanceTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].checked)?++count:count;

    if ($('#counterTreeviewUL'+idInstanceTreeview)[0].children.length == count)
    {
        $('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].checked=true;
        $('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].indeterminate=false;
    }
    else if (count==0)
    {
        $('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].checked=true;       
        $('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].indeterminate=false;        
    }
    else
    {
        $('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].checked=true;
        $('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].indeterminate=false;
    }   
        for (var i=0;i<$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children.length;i++)
    {   
        if (!$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].checked)
        {   
            $('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].checked=true;


       var fnInstance=$('#counterTreeviewUL'+idTreeview)[0].children[i].children[0].attributes[1].value;

       fnInstance=fnInstance.substr(15).substr(0,fnInstance.length-2);  
       var flagsInstance=fnInstance.split(new RegExp(","));


            var graph = {
                    id: seqId,
                    entityName: flags[6].substr(1).substr(0, flags[6].length - 2),
                    entity: flags[5].substr(1).substr(0, flags[5].length - 2),
                    idCounter: flags[4],
                    counterName: flags[3].substr(1).substr(0, flags[3].length - 2),
                    ivmanager: flags[7].substr(1).substr(0, flags[7].length - 2),
                    chart: null,
                    pointsToShowX: null,
                    borneInf: null,
                    unite: "",
                    idInstance: flagsInstance[2].substr(1).substr(0, flagsInstance[2].length - 2),
                    instanceName: flagsInstance[3].substr(1).substr(0, flagsInstance[3].length - 2),
                    listPdsNull: new Array(),
                    countInstance: idTreeview + "_" + i,
                    countGraph: -1
                };

            seqId++;            
            graphs[graphsLastId]=graph;             
            graphsLastId++;
        }
    }

 }
    graphsToLoad=false;
    updateAllGraphs();
    loading=false;

    if($('#counterTreeviewUL'+idInstanceTreeview).length == 0)
    {

      if($('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].checked)
        {
        countSelectedGraphs(graphsLastId, flags[5].substr(1).substr(0,flags[5].length-2), 0);
        }
      else 
        {
        countSelectedGraphs(graphsLastId, flags[5].substr(1).substr(0,flags[5].length-2), 0);
        }
    }

    else 
    {
    countSelectedGraphs(graphsLastId, flags[5].substr(1).substr(0,flags[5].length-2), 0);       
    }
}
```

Any insight into what's causing this seemingly random error would be much appreciated as I can't find much online regarding this error (the cases I've seen it occur are nothing like my one), thanks!

Comment: What's the value of `fn` after the first assignment?

Comment: @bfavaretto  It was equal to fn = selectGraph95 when I console.logged after var fn=$ statement and it was equal to fn = 5 when I console.logged after the fn=fn.substr statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
fn=fn.substr(12).substr(0,fn.length-2);
```

starts with making a substring, effectively stripping the first 12 letters away from the string and leaving you with "5". (The second `substr` does effectively nothing in this case)

Because fn is "5" when you assign `flags` then `flags` is also "5" which is a 1-character string and therefore `flags[6] == undefined` (or any index larger than 0). Just try these 3 lines in console:

```
var x = "5"; 
x[0]; // returns "5"
x[1]; // returns undefined
```

Comment: The function is clearly expecting something different from the `$('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].attributes[1].value` since it wants to split it on `','` into an array of strings to use as "flags" for the graph function

Comment: what do you get from `console.log($('#'+idSelectGraph));` right at the top of the function?

Comment: Ok, there is obviously some mismatch between that and what is intended, because the selector `$('#'+idSelectGraph)[0].attributes[1].value` just selects the id attribute from that element. I would talk to the "someone else" that wrote this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your readable code:

```
var graph = {
    id: seqId,
    entityName: flags[6].substr(1).substr(0, flags[6].length - 2),
    entity: flags[5].substr(1).substr(0, flags[5].length - 2),
    idCounter: flags[4],
    counterName: flags[3].substr(1).substr(0, flags[3].length - 2),
    ivmanager: flags[7].substr(1).substr(0, flags[7].length - 2),
    chart: null,
    pointsToShowX: null,
    borneInf: null,
    unite: "",
    idInstance: flagsInstance[2].substr(1).substr(0, flagsInstance[2].length - 2),
    instanceName: flagsInstance[3].substr(1).substr(0, flagsInstance[3].length - 2),
    listPdsNull: new Array(),
    countInstance: idTreeview + "_" + i,
    countGraph: -1
};
```

You **need** to make sure that every time you call `substr`, the "string" you are calling it on exists.

Comment: @user1394965 FF might just be hiding the error. double check and log everything to make sure.